# Re-use proguard-rules.pro file in multiple app modules

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, android-proguard

I have a project containing 2 modules that can be built into their own respective APK : a "mobile" module and a "tv" module.

Both of these buildable modules need the same proguard rules, but I don't want duplicate copies of the same proguard-rules.pro file in both the "mobile" and "tv" modules.

Is there a way I can put the proguard-rules.pro file in the project's root directory and reference this single proguard-rules.pro file in both of my buildable modules (mobile and tv)?

Comment: I'm not sure, but using relative path like "../" should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. You could change the structure of your project in something like this:

```
 root
 |---- mobile
       |---- build.gradle
 |---- tv
       |---- build.gradle
 |---- proguard-rules.pro
```

And in both `build.gradle` files of the modules, you can specify your proguard file by path:

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), '../proguard-rules.pro'
```